# Error: "Value br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray"

Tags: android

I took data from the web to display all the student lists but encountered this error. How to fix ?

> Error: "com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray"

This is my code.

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String urlGetData = "http://demokl.atwebpages.com/getdata.php";

private void GetData(String url) {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    // Get Json object from php page
                    studentArrayList.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            studentArrayList.add(new Student(jsonObject.getInt("ID"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("FullName"),
                                    jsonObject.getInt("YearOfBirth"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("Address")));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    studentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() { // Error link or server
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("AAA", error.toString());

                }
            });
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

*getdata.php*

```
<?php

require "dbCon.php";
// Get All data in student table
$query = "SELECT * FROM studenttable"; // student table
$data = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

// Create class Student
class Student {
    function Student($id, $fullname, $yearOfBirth, $address) {
        $this -> ID = $id;
        $this -> FullName = $fullname;
        $this -> YearOfBirth = $yearOfBirth;
        $this -> Address = $address;
    }
}

// Push each element to array 
$arrayStu = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    array_push($arrayStu, new Student($row['id'], $row['fullname'], $row['yearofbirth'], $row['address']));
}

// Export array to JSON data
echo json_encode($arrayStu);
```

?>

*dbCon.php*

```
<?php 

$connect = mysqli_connect("fdb26.awardspace.net", "2953966_demo", "khanhlee93", "2953966_demo"); // (server, name, pass, dbname)
mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

?>
```

Comment: It means that the response from your server could not be decoded by Volley into a valid JSONArray object.

You could temporarily replace the JsonArrayRequest with a StringRequest and dump the server response that makes it to your android client. This would allow you to view what makes it to your client from the server.

Comment: I tried to replace JsonArrayRequest by JsonStringRequest but can not call response.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: You should replace with StringRequest not JsonStringRequest.

Then dump the content of the response in the onSuccess method.
Tell us what you see there, please. By dump, I mean print out or log the response

Answer (score 0):

Change your request type **from**

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
```

**To**

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>()
```

Comment: I tried to replace JsonArrayRequest by JsonStringRequest but can not call response.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: Use this, **JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response); obj.getJSONObject("data")** to get any object from response

Comment: I was doing by your way but result is not show, only have a listview empty :(